# NodeJS mongo-express error: Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i'm trying to use Mongo-Express to lookup my mongoDB, I newbee, after i went under the user and pass i got error -> Cannot GET /

```
    var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');

var _ = require('underscore');
var async = require('async');
var utils = require('./utils');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var cons = require('consolidate');
var swig = require('swig');
var swigFilters = require('./filters');
var app = express();

var config = require('./config');

//Set up swig
app.engine('html', cons.swig);

Object.keys(swigFilters).forEach(function (name) {
    swig.setFilter(name, swigFilters[name]);
});

//App configuration
app.configure(function(){
  if(config.useBasicAuth){
    app.use(express.basicAuth(config.basicAuth.username, config.basicAuth.password));
  }
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('view options', {layout: false});
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(config.site.baseUrl,express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser(config.site.cookieSecret));
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: config.site.sessionSecret,
    key: config.site.cookieKeyName
  }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to learn from actual/updated tutorials. Actual express version is 4, and it removes:

```
 app.use(app.router);
```

(therefore my deduction of outdated tutorial) 
Second thing, i dont see in your code any routes. If you want to get responses from server, you need to write routes. For example:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from route');
});
```